# Quick Sort vs Merge Sort for nearly sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm, sorting

When dealing with an array that is nearly sorted which algorithm performs better quick sort or merge sort and why? I realize other algorithms might perform better than these given the situation.

Comment: _Almost sorted_ has many meanings. What is your definition?

Comment: For quick sort, if the middle value is chosen as the pivot, and the data is already sorted it will have O(n log(n)) time complexity. If the data is nearly sorted, it will take longer if due to data pattern, the pivot elements end up being bad choices. For basic merge sort, the number of moves is constant, and for ideal (sorted) data, the number of compares is reduced by a constant factor of 2, but still time complexity O(n log(n)). For an array of basic types like integers, quick sort is a bit faster than merge sort (like 15% or so).

Answer (score 0):

Both Quick Sort and Merge Sort are great for sorted arrays because for both algorithms the sorted array is kind of a good-case which lets them run in O(n).

However, Quick Sort has less bureaucratic overhead because it does everything in-place.  (On modern architectures it might even benefit from multiple processor cores, depending on the implementation.)

Merge Sort, on the other hand, builds new data structures (lists) in every recursion step, handing them back up to the caller who then merges these lists to become its result.  So even if this is also running in O(n), this will be slower (unless something weird is going on).  It will also need more memory than Quick Sort.

But keep in mind that Quick Sort in the worst case will still need O(n²) (while Merge Sort will not raise above O(n log n)), so if you only *hope* to have nearly sorted arrays, this should be considered.

Comment: You describe some incredibly naive merge sort implementation.

Comment: If quicksort is using first or last element as the pivot value, then already sorted data is one of the worst case O(n^2) patterns, and requires O(n) stack frames. For naive merge sort, the number of moves is always the same, only the number of compares is reduced (by a constant factor of 2) for already sorted data.

Comment: How ordering makes Quick Sort to perform with O(N) complexity? It is not adaptive.

Comment: @MBo A Quick Sort implementation for input which is rather sorted would use the middle element as pivot value and check upon iterating through the two sublists whether they are already sorted.  This can be done in O(n), and if everything is sorted, nothing more needs to be done.

Comment: @Alfe Seems you are talking about special kind of QuickSort especilally intended for sorted arrays ; -)  Emphasizing such logic - any sorting agorithm could be O(N) - just check for sortness before work.

Comment: @MBo Yeah, well, kind of.  Of course, a prior check for sortedness would let any sorting algorithm benefit from sorted input.  But in case of the Quick Sort, this check makes sense on any recursion level, so for this algorithm it seems prudent in general.  This is not the case for other algorithms.

Comment: First partition makes ~n comparisons and no swaps. But does not give information whether halves are sorted. Second level partitions make 2*n/2 comparisons and no swaps.. Last level (log2(n)-th) partitions makes n/2*2 comparisons. Ideal n*logn behaviior but not linear. Perhaps I don't see what you meant. In any case, seems that author isn't very interesting in subtleties :)

Comment: Any partition can keep track of the information whether any unsorted spot was found.  Then the first partition already returns the sorted array after O(n).

Answer (score -1):

Partial ordering does not change speed of Quick Sort algorithm - it is not **adaptive** in general (while some implementation might exist, but with worse productivity).

[Adaptive sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort) (though too few information)

There is [Natural Merge Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort) that exploits pre-ordering and benefits from it well (while the most widely used Merge Sort approach is not adaptive)